# Does the line following the goroutine calling line starts earlier than first line of goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

Here's the code:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    messages := make(chan string, 1)
    go func(c chan string) {
        c <- "Hi"
    }(messages)
    select {
    case msg := <-messages:
        fmt.Println("received message", msg)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no message received")
    }
}
```

It outputs `no message received`.
Or this code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func f(from string) {
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println(from, ":", i)
    }
}

func main() {
    go f("goroutine")

    go func(msg string) {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }("going")

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

unexpectedly prints

```
going
goroutine : 0
goroutine : 1
goroutine : 2
```

Despite of the fact that goroutine with `going` called later than the counter. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no execution ordering guarantees between multiple goroutines. Only when two goroutines exchange data using a channel, or synchronize using another synchronization mechanism ordering guarantees can be established. In your case, you happened to observe an execution where one goroutine happens to run before another. When you run it multiple times, you may observe different orderings.